# How to add background image to <area> tags for pins on a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have been tasked to create a map with pin points and roll overs but the direction I was given was to use hot spots. I told my lead developer there were better things out there we could use but to no avail. I am stuck using a very light plugin called rwdImageMaps this converts my cords to a responsive image. I need to create pinpoints in the spots I marked off but I am not sure how to do this on the  attribute. Any help would be very grateful since the demo my dev sent me uses a map image with the pins on it and then to add his roll over effect he loads an entire new map which only changes the color of the text. I need it to roll over and grow revealing the locations description of some kind example code and images below. Thanks for everyone's input.

Ill explain the pins - They have a pin like icon along with a label name of the city/ country then when you roll over them it extends revealing more information of that location. Can I even achieve this with how I have this currently? I do not mind changing this code to be something better that can achieve this outcome.

[image: Normal state of pin]

[image: Rollover state of pin]

```
<script src='js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();

    $('area').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
    });
</script>

<img src="images/worldMap.jpg" width="1170" height="820" usemap="#worldMap" class="worldMap" alt="" />
    <map name="worldMap" class="hidden-xs">
        <area shape="circle" coords="200,320,15" class="marker hidden-xs" href="#chicago" title="Chicago" alt="Chicago" />
        <area shape="circle" coords="350,580,15" class="marker hidden-xs" href="#saopaulo" title="Sao Paulo" alt="Sao Paulo" />
        <area shape="circle" coords="540,310,15" class="marker hidden-xs" href="#amsterdam" title="Amsterdam" alt="Amsterdam" />
        <area shape="circle" coords="810,455,15" class="marker hidden-xs" href="#Mumbai" title="Mumbai" alt="Mumbai" />
        <area shape="circle" coords="940,405,15" class="marker hidden-xs" href="#Shanghai" title="Shanghai" alt="Shanghai" />
    </map>
```

Comment: Just tried something like this but jQuery isn't working on these <area> attributes. Please help.lol 

`$('#chicago')(function(){
     $(this).parent().css("background-image", "url('http://placehold.it/71x60') no-repeat")
 });`